# LayoutInflater messing up the UI

Tags: java, android, android-layout

## My goal

1. Navigate to an item on navigation tab bar (the view opens on the ViewPager).
2. Then I click on the button inside the view being shown by the ViewPager, the button method is `postForm` (code below).
3. It's supposed to hide the ViewPager, and show the ConstraintLayout and inflate activity_post_form.xml on it.
4. Works but messes up the UI.

## Code

```
public void postForm(View view) {
    //Set ViewPager Invisible
    ViewPager viewp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
    viewp.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //Set the constraint layout visible so we can inflate the view on it
    ConstraintLayout item = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.inConstraint);
    item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Inflate and add
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_post_form, null);
    item.addView(child);
}
```

## Design

[image]

## Results

[image]

## Main Activity

[image]

## XML for the Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#423752"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearRootView">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/inConstraint"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
        android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:ntb_badge_gravity="top"
        app:ntb_badge_position="right"
        app:ntb_badged="true"
        app:ntb_scaled="true"
        app:ntb_tinted="true"
        app:ntb_title_mode="all"
        app:ntb_titled="true"
        app:ntb_swiped="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You added no LayoutParams, so how does it know where to add within the layout?

Comment: Less code indeed, but doesn't work. I get a [blank screen](http://prntscr.com/e8c4pv).  @cricket_007 Would you please enlighten me how to add the LayoutParams in this situation? I'm kind of new to android.

Comment: It's very complicated via code :) The `addView` method takes some extra parameters that you can read over in the API

Comment: Is there a way to **not** do it via code?